# Reduce the White Space in Two Column Format

Tags: equations

I noticed that there are several white black space in between any theorem or lemma and the next sentence or equation and the next sentence, for example :

[image: lemma]

[image: optimality]

Is there any common code to reduce the white blank space to be used in overleaf TeX Live 2022 with two column format?

Here is my current code for the equation:

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum


\begin{equation} \label{eq:Opt_gap}
{\emph{Optimality gap}} = \left(\frac{\lambda_{sequence} - \psi _{sequence}}{\psi_{sequence}} \right)(100\%)
\end{equation}

\end{equation}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Please give a MWE can recurrent.

Answer (score 2):

You ask,

> Is there any common code to reduce the white blank space [above an equation] with two column format?

Short answer: Yes. Longer answer: Don't allow all-blank lines above `\begin{equation}`, or the start of *any* displayed-math material, for that matter.

By the way, this piece of advice applies to both one-column and two-column layouts.

[image]

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{newtxmath} % optional: Times Roman math font
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{lipsum} % filler text
\newcommand\vn[1]{\textit{#1}} % how to typeset variable names

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1] % Note: no blank line below this line
\begin{equation} \label{eq:Opt_gap}
{\vn{Optimality gap}} = \left(\frac{\lambda_{\vn{sequence}} - \psi_{\vn{sequence}}}{\psi_{\vn{sequence}}} \right)(100\%)
\end{equation}

\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```